# Wondering how to compare sets

Tags: java

Im trying to create a program that takes two types [like pokemon] where you select two, and the computer selects two, and then a comparison occurs saying who won.

Comment: You need to define your rules better so that we can understand them better, and you should be careful with terms as "double" has special meaning in Java as a floating point type, and I don't think you mean this.

Comment: What happens in the case of a tie?

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams : self destructs!

Answer (score 1):

Try implementing a [Comparator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)? It's super effective.

(Of course, if it's like Pokemon then you might want to rig it so that the computer wins more often...)